# Python remove strings with a pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my project I have comments that I will have to process (tokenize spem etc). In those comments I have for example 17.20 or 17:20 that displays the time and 20' that displays the seconds. How to remove them?

```
>>> m = re.search('([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)+','Παρήγγειλα 21.29 και ήρθε 22.17')
>>> m.group(0)
  '21.29'
>>> m.group(1)
  '21.29'
>>> m.group(2)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  IndexError: no such group
```

I use reg and I have the above code and output...how to have both (21.29 and 22.17)?
I want to remove them from my comments.

Comment: Using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: You sir, need to do research before you post.

Comment: Are you able to post some of these comments in full? It would help to  know the context.

Comment: Please describe how you are retrieving these comments (http request data, database, other storage) and how the data is formatted so that people can give you useful advice.

Comment: @Martin Evans an example of the content is this  παραδοση μεσα σε 15' λεπτα  for the minutes and Παρήγγειλα 21.29 και ήρθε 22.17  for the time

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **regex**, and the Python regex library `re`. Regexes are very useful, implemented in almost every modern language, and there is a lot of information about them available, including many tutorials and explanations.

The regex is a string which includes special characters such as `*` or `|`, which is used to 'match' your string to see if it conforms to a certain pattern. (It's like a much more powerful version of using '*' or '?' to select groups of files whose names are all similar.) You can retrieve parts of the string, which correspond to bracketed groups in the regex.

For example:

```
m = re.match("(.*day) (\d{1,2}:\d\d) (a|p)m", "Monday 3:15 am")
```

will return a match, because the regex specifies anything ending with 'day', then a space, then either 1 or 2 digits (`\d` matches any digit), then `:`, then two digits, then a space, then either `p` or `a`, then `m`. The pieces of the string which match the parts of the regex in brackets can be accessed with `m.group()`.

```
>>> m.group(1)
'Monday'
>>> m.group(2)
'3:15'
>>> m.group(3)
'am'
```

The full documentation for the `re` library is at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html It takes a long time to become an regex expert, but there are numerous resources, including online apps to test your regex against different strings, which will help you figure out the correct regex for your problem.

Comment: i want the 3:15 to have it separate it in '3' ':' '15' so i can remove it later